# Lock an action while it is in process

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC application where i call a jquery post method on textbox blur function. 
The problem is the form has many input fields and on each input field blur call same ajax method, and if users click in and out in different text boxes very fast, the ajax method call two three times and resulted in wrong result.

Here is an example

```
    Flight 1
    Airline     Flight #    Class         Date
S1  TextBox1    TextBox2    TextBox3      TextBox4 
S2  TextBox1    TextBox2    TextBox3      TextBox4 
S3  TextBox1    TextBox2    TextBox3      TextBox4
```

One solution to this which i tired is to Disable all input                  filed when calling ajex like this

```
function Submit() {
     $('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $.post("/ItineraryBuilder/GetFlightData", { opportunityId: oppID}, function (data) 
     {
          $("#DivResult").html(data);
          $('input').removeAttr("disabled");
     }
}
```

This disable all input fields and restrict user to in-out from textboxes frequently which in turn do not call Ajax post again and again. But as soon as input fields are disabled, focus has been also lost and make it difficult to use TAB in this case.

So is there any way i can lock down the ajax call or Controller/Action for a while so until one action is in process another will not start, or any other better way to do this?

Hope i clear my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($.active){ 
  //there's an ajax function running
}else{ 
  //there's no ajax function running
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an overlay instead.

I've created a small plugin called ElementOverlay. You can use it like this:

```
function Submit() {
     $('#yourForm').elementOverlay();

     $('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $.post("/ItineraryBuilder/GetFlightData", { opportunityId: oppID}, function (data) 
     {
          $('#yourForm').elementOverlay('destroy');

          $("#DivResult").html(data);
          $('input').removeAttr("disabled");
     }
}
```

That will only overlay the form, so the user can work with the rest of the page.

Script: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.jquery.tools/blob/master/Source/jquery.griffin.elementoverlay.js (click on the "Raw" button to download it)

Comment: Does this work if the user tabs through the inputs? Seems to me the form would still be accessible that way...

Comment: Put the overlay over the tab panel.. `$('#theTabId').elementOverlay();`

Comment: Ah, maybe I was not precise enough - I meant using the tab key to jump to the next input - doesn't that still work?

Comment: So this won't help if the user uses the tab key to click through the inputs. Which probably many users will do. That's why I was asking.

Comment: Well, that's your subjective opinion. My own experience is that overlays make users wait before doing anything else. It's up to the OP to decide which solution he sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you like your own solution except for the lost focus you can do the following.

I used the complicated "each" function to determine the next input because "next()" probably won't work since you seem to put your form in a table. By the way you were missing a closing ");" on your post call.

```
    $('input').on('blur', function(){
      $('input').attr('disabled', true);
      $(this).addClass('last-edited');
      var tagnext = false;
      $('input').each(function(){
          if(tagnext){
             $(this).addClass('next-focus');
             tagnext = false;
          }
          if($(this).hasClass('last-edited')){
             $(this).removeClass('last-edited');
             tagnext = true;
          }
      });
      Submit();           
    });



   function Submit(){
      $.post('/ItineraryBuilder/GetFlightData', { opportunityId: oppID}, function (data) 
      {
         $('#DivResult').html(data);
         $('.next-focus').focus();
         $('input').removeAttr('disabled');
      });
   }
```